# ESXi Server has locked with .lock4 file suffix on all vmdk's after crash SAVE ME!

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmdk, ransomware

My ESXI server was running from a USB stick that got corrupted and as a result prevented my server from booting. I fixed this by reinstalling ESXI on a new memory stick and began re-adding all of my VMs.

However when I try to start them up it is saying that it cannot find the VMDK file, and it appears to have added a suffix of .lock4 to all files in all of my VM folders.

I've tried removing the lock4 suffix, but this does not seem to help.

I've been sitting in a freezing cold server room for 5hrs now, so any help is really appreciated :)

mail1-uk.server.com-aux.xml                mail1-uk.server.com.vmx                    vmware-2.log.lock4                         vmware-5.log.lock4
mail1-uk.server.com-flat.vmdk              mail1-uk.server.com.vmxf                   vmware-3.log                               vmware.log
mail1-uk.server.com.nvram                  vmware-1.log                               vmware-3.log.lock4                         vmware.log.lock4
mail1-uk.server.com.vmdk.lock4             vmware-1.log.lock4                         vmware-4.log                               vmx-mail1-uk.server.com-3109620673-1.vswp

Answer (score 4):

You've been hit with a VMware ESXi variant of ransomware.
Your VMware datastore's contents have been encrypted.
The attacker likely got into your system via ESXi SSH.

There may be a ransom note in the top level of the datastore. Look for a "Readme" text file

See: https://blogs.vmware.com/security/2022/09/esxi-targeting-ransomware-the-threats-that-are-after-your-virtual-machines-part-1.html